# How to log data in a single line in this case in java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging

Setting data like this how can I log in a single line

```
OrgMap Patient = new OrgMap();
Information Info = request.Information().get(0);// data coming from payload

               if (Info.getFirstName() != null) {
                    org.setFirstName(Info.getFirstName());
                    log.info( firstname has set in orgTable");
                }
                if (Info.getPatientMiddleName() != null) {
                    org.setMiddleName(Info.getMiddleName());
                    log.info(" firstname has set in orgTable");
                }
                if (Info.getPatientLastName() != null) {
                    org.setLastName(Info.getLastName());
                    log.info("LastName has set in orgTable");
                }
                if (tInfo.getDOB() != null) {
                    org.setDob(Info.getDOB());
                    log.info(" DOB has set in orgTable");
                }
                if (patientInfo.getGender() != null) {
                    orgPatient.setGender(Info.getGender());
                    log.info("Gender has set in orgTable");
                }
```

Current Loging output like this

```
firstname has set in orgTable
LastName has set in orgTable
Email has set in orgTable
```

Required like this

```
FirstName,LastName,Gender,DOB has set in orgTable
```

How can I set

Comment: just use a StringBuilder or String concatenation to create the String to log, and only actually put one single log statement after you've checked the conditions and created the line to log

Comment: That's far too granular an approach to logging. At best you want `log.info(info + " set in orgTable");` and of course that class should already implement `toString` properly. [`info`](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions)
(as all other variables) should begin lower case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
    OrgMap org = new OrgMap();
    Information info = request.Information().get(0); // Assuming Information class and its methods

    List<String> listOfWords = new ArrayList<>();

    if (info.getFirstName() != null) {
        org.setFirstName(info.getFirstName());
        listOfWords.add("FirstName,");
    }
    if (info.getMiddleName() != null) {
        org.setMiddleName(info.getMiddleName());
        listOfWords.add("MiddleName");
    }
    if (info.getLastName() != null) {
        org.setLastName(info.getLastName());
        listOfWords.add("LastName");
    }
    if (info.getDOB() != null) {
        org.setDob(info.getDOB());
        listOfWords.add("DOB");
    }
    if (info.getGender() != null) {
        org.setGender(info.getGender());
        listOfWords.add("Gender");
    }

    if (listOfWords.size() > 0) {
        String words = String.join(",", listOfWords);
        log.info(words + " has set in orgTable");
    }
```

Comment: why adding a list and a needless loop in the mix? you're also not taking into account that the last added element shouldn't add a ",", and we can't know for sure what the last added element will be

Comment: length function showing error

Comment: Yup sorry my bad... I'll edit

Comment: because of the join it doesn't apply a , at the last element. Why not apply a loop? Of course there is multiple solutions for this, this is just one of them

Answer (score 0):

You can handle with that through Java Stream. Here is the code snippet shown below

```
OrgMap org = new OrgMap();
Information info = request.Information().get(0); // data coming from payload

Map<String, Consumer<OrgMap>> setters = new HashMap<>();
setters.put("FirstName", org::setFirstName);
setters.put("MiddleName", org::setMiddleName);
setters.put("LastName", org::setLastName);
setters.put("DOB", org::setDob);
setters.put("Gender", org::setGender);

String fieldsSet = setters.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> getField(info, entry.getKey()) != null)
    .peek(entry -> entry.getValue().accept(getField(info, entry.getKey())))
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

if (!fieldsSet.isEmpty()) {
    log.info(fieldsSet + " have set in orgTable");
}

// Helper method to get the field from Information
private static Object getField(Information info, String fieldName) {
    switch (fieldName) {
        case "FirstName":
            return info.getFirstName();
        case "MiddleName":
            return info.getMiddleName();
        case "LastName":
            return info.getLastName();
        case "DOB":
            return info.getDOB();
        case "Gender":
            return info.getGender();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```